# How to allow javascript compilation with typescript errors,

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using vs code with create-react-app --typescript, if i get any type errors i see it in the browser and typescript prevents compilation. i would like to see the errors only in google console and terminal but allow the valid js to compile.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEkBH.png)

Comment: "and allow valid js to compile" The code from your image (which should be included in text form in the question btw) is valid js, but it is not valid typescript and you are writing typescript and not javascript. Therefore it is correct for typescript not to compile it. So what is your question? Do you want to turn off the error? Do you want to fix it? Do you want to disable the prompt? Or do you want to compile even when there are errors?

Comment: hello Patrick, sorry if it's not very clear ... I want to be able to see the error in the console/terminal but to be able to compile, for example: if i am assigning string to number, the error with display in the console but i wil not see this in the browser
hope its clear

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. But you can put `//@ts-ignore` before the line which contains the error.
In your case:

```
{/* 
  //@ts-ignore */} //this will do the trick
{value.galleryId} <DragHandle />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack the [**ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin) will achieve something like you want to do. This plugin will separate the compile process from the error reporting. After you have installed and imported this plugin, you will need to set the `ts-loader` to compile only mode. In the plugins section the plugin needs to be injected, to do the error reporting separately.

```js
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
//...
   module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [
            // ...
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                // disable ts checker - will run it in fork plugin leater
                transpileOnly: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }, 
   // ..
   ],
   plugins: [
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
         tsconfig: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')
      }),
   // ...
```